# Print to Console in Real Time Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, flush

I am currently writing a script that attempts to bind to as many servers that are in a specific conf.ini file. I have a for loop that will attempt to bind based on the information in that file, for each server.

I would like there to be a real time output of what is happening i.e .  ('Attempting to bind to server...' or 'Bind successful') however my script waits until it has connected to all the servers before printing any output.

I have tried running python -u script.py and sys.stdout.flush() but nothing seems to be working.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

```
for file in files:
    conf_file = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
    conf_file.read(file)

    connection_section = 'LDAP'

    # Get Information from .ini Files
    try:
        hostname = conf_file.get(connection_section, 'hostname')
        port = conf_file.get(connection_section, 'port')
        username = conf_file.get(connection_section, 'username')
        password = conf_file.get(connection_section, 'password')
    except ConfigParser.NoOptionError:
        print("One or more options in {} is invalid!".format(file))

    print("Attempting to bind with {}:{}...".format(hostname, port))
    sys.stdout.flush()

    try:
        connection = ldap.open(hostname, int(port))
        connection.set_option(ldap.OPT_REFERRALS, 0)
        connection.simple_bind_s(username, password)
        print("Bind Success Attempting to query views...\n")
        sys.stdout.flush()

    except ldap.LDAPError as error:
        print("There was an issue while attempting to bind to {}:{}. 
[{}]\n".format(hostname, port, error[0]['desc']))
```

EDIT: I added a screenshot of the output with a timestamp
[image]

Comment: threads or multiprocessing

Comment: Are you sure about that? I cannot see anything what would block "printing in realtime".

Comment: I'm sure. The program waits about 20-25 seconds then outputs the 'Attempting to bind' and 'bind success' messages three times at the same time @Joozty

Comment: How are you _running_ this script?

Comment: @DavisHerring I'm running 'python script.py' but I have also tried 'python -u script.py'